# Javascript(NO jquery) copy file object from one array to new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am building a music and video site where users upload their own files. While running tests, i found that some of the files would not copy to my server (net:ERR_CONNECTION_RESET), and it would stop the function from running. That's fine. But, it abandons the function, leaving unprocessed copies in the array. 
Example: I have 10 files i am uploading. The function fails at index 5. That leaves 4 files untouched (indexes 0,1,2,3 and 4 return with success).
 My solution, in my way of thinking, is to simply copy the remaining files into a new array and send back to the function. Simple, right?
NOT!!
According to other SO questions, it seems copying with slice(),splice, or other methods only work on primitive types (string, number, etc.). i need to move/copy/delete the first 5 items out of the array, and send the unfinished uploads back to be processed. Just reloading these files after is not an option, as sometimes i upload up to 50 at a time. Imagine.... reloading 45 over again... only to have it  fail again after another 3 or 4.... May be ok for me, but clients and users will not be too impressed...
Is there any way to copy a portion of one FILE array into another, using native Javascript, and NOT an external library? (no JQuery...) Not looking for "the code,plz", but a direction of where to look... methods, or functions that can achieve this?
 Tx in advance :)

Comment: Gonna need some code...

Comment: Why not just trim those files that were processed succussfully from the array which is better than copying!

Comment: Interesting... Something i will look into.

Comment: Thumbs up on that solution :) if it was an answer, i would have voted it up !